# AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'cache'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have installed Django 1.10. I need to import the loafing but not able to import it. I am trying to connect my django app with elasticsearch using Haystack and wanted to build index. The code I want to run is

> python manage.py rebuild_index

The error I get is:

```
    base ---dir
/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/ad-tracking-django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catalog/models.py", line 79, in <module>
    for model_cls in connected_models():
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catalog/utils.py", line 19, in connected_models
    yield apps.cache.get_model(*model_str.split('.'))
AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'cache'
```

According to my research the reason behind the error is because of the 'catalog' lib. Is there any alternative to this in Django 1.10? I have got 100s of errors even if I change a bunch of codes

Errors I have got are as follows:

> ImportError: No module named util
>
> ImportError: No module named loading
>
> ImportError: No module named generic

Comment: Which django catalog lib are you using here?

Comment: I found out that 'catalog' is not supported by Django 1.10 so I deleted the catalog lib. I currently forgot what I used instead but that worked out. Can you reply to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410041/requesterror-transporterror400-uparsing-exception